# Spring urls don't appear on included nested jsp file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, include, directive

I have a JSP file which includes another JSP file.

For example, this is my template.jsp which include subview.jsp:

```html
    <body>
     <spring:url value="/resources/images/" var="imagePath" />      
     <jsp:include page="subview.jsp" />      
</body>
```

and in subview.jsp I can't access `${imagePath}`. I can access `${imagePath}` by using `<%@include file="subview.jspf"%>`, but I have to use include action since the subview.jsp name is dynamically assigned from the controller. Thanks

Comment: Set imagePath as request parameter then get it in subview.jsp